# Escape character in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get escape character like below:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_25
```

Here is the code in batch script:

```
set AGNT_JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME% SET
set AGNT_JAVA_HOME=%AGNT_JAVA_HOME:\\=\\\\%
```

But the value coming is :

```
AGNT_JAVA_HOME value is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

Any idea what need to be added here to get the value as first line.

Answer (score 2):

The escape character for batch is `^`, not `\`.

The `\` literal does not require escaping.

So all you need is:

```
set AGNT_JAVA_HOME=%AGNT_JAVA_HOME:\=\\%
```

But it is safer to enclose the entire SET assignment in quotes, just in case AGNT_JAVA_HOME contains a poison character like `&`.

```
set "AGNT_JAVA_HOME=%AGNT_JAVA_HOME:\=\\%"
```